# Remove underline from HTML

Tags: html

I am looking for how to remove the underline from this bit of HTML

I tried this but have no idea where to place it in this line. (I am not a developer)

```
<a href="%%unsubscribe%%"><span style="color:#15BECE;">Unsubscribe</span></a> from email communications<br>
```

Comment: a { text-decoration:none; }

Comment: @Kelly Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54221855/9819031)

Comment: Apologies - I am not a developer. I added this bit to my html but it isn't working. I am guessing because of where I placed it?

Comment: <a href="%%unsubscribe%%"><span style="color:#15BECE;style="text-decoration:none">Unsubscribe</span></a> from email communications</p>

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to do this.

In the `<head>` tag of your `.htm`(or `.html`) file, add the following code:

```
<style>
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
    } 
<style>
```

For adding further styles, you can use styling on the tag:

```
<style>
    a:link {
        /*a normal <a> tag*/
        text-decoration: none;
        color: value;
    } 

    a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
        color: /*Your desired color when cursor is on the link*/;
    } 

    a:visited {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: /*Your desired color when link is clicked and visited*/;
    } 

    a:active {
        text-decoration: underline;
        color: /*Your desired color when link is clicked*/;
    } 
<style>
```

Comment: Apologies - I am not a developer. I added this bit to my html but it isn't working. I am guessing because of where I placed it?

Comment: <a href="%%unsubscribe%%"><span style="color:#15BECE;style="text-decoration:none">Unsubscribe</span></a> from email communications</p>

Comment: This is the wrong way to do like what you are doing. First of all your link seems to be wrong

Comment: also you have used `style` in inline style while using `<span>`

Comment: also have you added this to your `<head>` tag? Can you please provide me the link to your site so that I can check over there?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone!! 
This is the bit that fixed my problem. I know this was very novice and appreciate your help!

```
<a style="text-decoration:none"><span style="color:#15BECE">Unsubscribe</span></a> from email communications</p>
```